# Manipulating a Write File Class

Tags: python, file-io

The following classes work, I'm just trying to manipulate the top class to work for me:

This class writes the file:

```
class saveRegister :
    def __init__( <--snip--> #defines some of the variables in the write function

    def writeToFile(self,file) :

        file.write(... #saves values in a specific format
```

This used the above class to write is what I based mine very quickly on:

```
class Prep :
    def writeToFilename( self, filename, registerNames ) :
        file = open( filename, 'w+' )
        for register in self.registers : #format here same as in my code
            register.writeToFile(file)
        file.close()
```

I'm trying to reuse their code to work with mine in a different file, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. As a quick test, I wanted to write this to a file using the above:

```
from mylib.saveFiles import saveRegister

def saveStateValues(self, msg):

    filename="/tmp/test.txt"
    reg_test = {"HelloWorld":0x5}

    file.open(filename, 'w+')
    for register in reg_test:
        register.saveRegister.writeToFile(file)
    file.close()
```

The written file isn't even displayed which is strange because when I've used the file.open() method before here, it works. I can't give you an error message as there are none  (for various annoying reasons, this is translated into Java - but that shouldn't be important, so when something subtle doesn't work, it just doesn't tell you).

Comment: What exactly is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: I was curious to see if there is anything blatantly wrong with my code. It won't even open a file for me to write in.

Comment: Or if there is some weird rule in python where I can't write to a file where I'm calling from an external class... That sort of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you are doing, but there are rather a lot of bugs in your `saveStateValues` method.

`file` is a built-in function in Python - it is actually a synonym for `open` - and there is no such thing as `file.open`.  The function returns an opened file, but you throw that away rather than storing it in a variable: then you pass the function itself into your `writeToFile`, rather than the file you've just opened.

Then there are even more issues with your loop. You iterate through `reg_test`, which is a dictionary, so each value of `register` is a key from that dict. But for some reason you treat that as an object and try to access its `saveRegister` attribute. `saveRegister` is a class you've imported, so that makes no sense. What you should be doing is instantiating an instance of saveRegister outside the loop, then passing each value to the `writeToFile` method.

Putting it all together:

```
file_to_write = open(filename, 'w+')
save_register = saveRegister()
for register in reg_test:
    save_register.writeToFile(file_to_write, register)
file_to_write.close()
```

(I'm pretty sure this is not totally correct, because you aren't doing anything with the values from `reg_test`, just the keys. We probably need to know what exactly `saveRegister.writeToFile` is expecting.)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm just getting a bit too ahead of myself early on